# Data abstraction that really allows isolating implementation from the user in C++

Tags: c++, abstraction

I hesitate to ask this question, because it's deceitfully simple one. Except I fail to see a solution.

I recently made an attempt to write a simple program that would be somewhat oblivious to what engine renders its UI.

Everything looks great on paper, but in fact, theory did not get me far.

Assume my tool cares to have an `IWindow` with `IContainer` that hosts an `ILabel` and `IButton`. That's 4 UI elements. Abstacting each one of these is a trivial task. I can create each of these elements with Qt, Gtk, motif - you name it.

I understand that in order for implementation (say, `QtWindow` with `QtContainer`) to work, the abstraction (`IWindow` along with `IContainer`) have to work, too: `IWindow` needs to be able to accept `IContainer` as its child: That requires either that

- I can add any of the UI elements to container, or
- all the UI elements inherit from a single parent

That is theory which perfectly solves the abstraction issue. Practice (or implementation) is a whole other story. In order to make implementation to work along with abstraction - the way I see it I can either

- pollute the abstraction with ugly calls exposing the implementation (or giving hints about it) - killing the concept of abstraction, or
- add casting from the abstraction to something that the implementation understands (`dynamic_cast<>()`).
- add a global map pool of `ISomething` instances to UI specific elements (`map<IElement*, QtElement*>()`) which would be somewhat like casting, except done by myself.

All of these look ugly. I fail to see other alternatives here - is this where data abstraction concept actually fails? Is casting the only alternative here?

**Edit**

I have spent some time trying to come up with optimal solution and it seems that this is something that just can't be simply done with C++. Not without casting, and not with templates as they are.

The solution that I eventually came up with (after messing a lot with interfaces and how these are defined) looks as follows:

### 1. There needs to be a parametrized base interface that defines the calls

The base interface (let's call it `TContainerBase` for Containers and `TElementBase` for elements) specifies methods that are expected to be implemented by containers or elements. That part is simple.

The definition would need to look something along these lines:

```
template <typename Parent>
class TElementBase : public Parent {
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

template <typename Parent>
class TContainerBase : public Parent {
    virtual void AddElement(TElementBase<Parent>* element) = 0;
};
```

### 2. There needs to be a template that specifies inheritance.

That is where the first stage of separation (engine vs ui) comes. At this point it just wouldn't matter what type of backend is driving the rendering. And here's the interesting part: as I think about it, the only language successfully implementing this is Java. The template would have to look something along these lines:

General:

```
template<typename Engine>
class TContainer : public TContainerBase<Parent> {
    void AddElement(TElementBase<Parent>* element) {
        // ...
    }
};

template<typename Engine>
class TElement : public TElementBase<Parent> {
    void DoSomething() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

### 3. UI needs to be able to accept just `TContainers` or `TElements`

that is, it would have to ignore what these elements derive from. That's the second stage of separation; after all everything it cares about is the `TElementBase` and `TContainerBase` interfaces. In Java that has been solved with introduction of question mark. In my case, I could simply use in my UI:

```
TContainer<?> some_container;
TElement<?> some_element;
container.AddElement(&element);
```

There's no issues with virtual function calls in vtable, as they are exactly where the compiler would expect them to be. The only issue would be here ensuring that the template parameters are same in both cases. Assuming the backend is a single library - that would work just fine.

The three above steps would allow me to write my code disregarding backend entirely (and safely), while backends could implement just about anything there was a need for.

I tried this approach and it turns to be pretty sane. The only limitation was the compiler. Instantiating class and casting them back and forth here is counter-intuitive, but, unfortunately, necessary, mostly because with template inheritance you can't extract just the base class itself, that is, you can't say any of:

```
class IContainerBase {};

template <typename Parent>
class TContainerBase : public (IContainerBase : public Parent) {}
```

nor

```
class IContainerBase {};
template <typename Parent>
typedef class IContainerBase : public Parent TContainerBase;
```

(note that in all the above solutions it *feels* perfectly natural and sane just to rely on `TElementBase` and `TContainerBase` - and the generated code works perfectly fine if you cast `TElementBase<Foo>` to `TElementBase<Bar>` - so it's just language limitation).

Anyway, these final statements (typedef of class A inheriting from B and class X having base class A inheriting from B) are just rubbish in C++ (and would make the language harder than it already is), hence the only way out is to follow one of the supplied solutions, which I'm very grateful for.

Thank you for all help.

Comment: Try to abstract your program's logic from its UI code. So that a table of data doesn't directly render itself to the UI. Instead it contains an abstract component of some kind which does that. That component can be tailored for different UI engines somewhere the logic doesn't care about.

Comment: if `QtWindow` implements `IWindow` and `GtkContainer` implements `IContainer`, what's to stop me from adding a `GtkContainer` as a child of a `QtWindow`?  I think that's the root of your problem:  you've abstracted the different kinds of UI components from *each other*, not just from the application.

Comment: Some clarification to the above:

The problem I'm struggling with is at the boundary between `IContainer` and `IElement`, in other words, I can add the method: `IContainer::Add(IElement*)` to the abstraction, but -- what about implementation? Obviously, the implementation would receive the `IElement*` as well, which then it would have to cast, or otherwise the `IElement` would need to export a custom structure that would be understandable to the UI implementation. Are these the only two ways? That's where I fail...

Comment: Yes you will need to have casts in your glue layer. One cast per UI element class (or just one cast, if you templatize it) Hardly a catastrophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Object Orientation here. OO has a particular method of achieving generic code: by type erasure. The `IWindow` base class interface erases the exact type, which in your example would be a `QtWindow`. In C++ you can get back some erased type information via RTTI, i.e. `dynamic_cast`.

However, in C++ you can also use templates. Don't implement `IWindow` and `QtWindow`, but implement `Window<Qt>`. This allows you to state that `Container<Foo>` accepts a `Window<Foo>` for any possible `Foo` window library. The compiler will enforce this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is the kind of situation the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) is intended to address.

> The abstract factory pattern provides a way to encapsulate a group of individual factories that have a common theme without specifying their concrete classes. In normal usage, the client software creates a concrete implementation of the abstract factory and then uses the generic interface of the factory to create the concrete objects that are part of the theme. The client doesn't know (or care) which concrete objects it gets from each of these internal factories, since it uses only the generic interfaces of their products. This pattern separates the details of implementation of a set of objects from their general usage and relies on object composition, as object creation is implemented in methods exposed in the factory interface.

Comment: That's very close. That would certainly work if I aimed at covering only single UI engine - this design pattern works perfectly with just Qt. or just Gtk. I can add method, say, `IElement::GetGtkWidget()` that would allow `IContainer` to accept anyone implementing `IElement` interface.

If you go one level up, that is, you want to be completely UI-engine agnostic, the problem arises: can you ensure that the implementation of your abstraction knows how to access its objects without casting?

Comment: The abstract factory insulates your clients from needing to know or reference your concrete implementation types of `IWindow` etc. but yes, you will still need to `dynamic_cast` an `IContainer` to a `QtContainer` inside your `QtWindow` in some situations. This is somewhat inevitable - if you are doing implementation specific things then you need to deal with concrete implementations. If you are doing non-implementation specific things then they should be pulled up into the base class where you can operate on the abstract types.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a wrapper capable of abstracting libraries like Qt and Gtk doesn't seems a trivial tasks to me. But talking more generally about your design problem, maybe you could use templates to do the mapping between the abstract interface and a specific implementation. For example:

Abstract interface **IWidget.h**

```
template<typename BackendT>
class IWidget
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        backend.doSomething();
    }

private:
    BackendT backend;
};
```

Qt implementation **QtWidget.h**:

```
class QtWidget
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        // qt specifics here
        cout << "qt widget" << endl;
    }
};
```

Gtk implementation **GtkWidget.h**:

```
class GtkWidget
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        // gtk specifics here
        cout << "gtk widget" << endl;
    }
};
```

Qt backend **QtBackend.h**:

```
#include "QtWidget.h"
// include all the other gtk classes you implemented...
#include "IWidget.h"

typedef IWidget<QtWidget> Widget;
// map all the other classes...
```

Gtk backend **GtkBackend.h**:

```
#include "GtkWidget.h"
// include all the other gtk classes you implemented...
#include "IWidget.h"

typedef IWidget<GtkWidget> Widget;
// map all the other classes...
```

Application:

```
// Choose the backend here:
#include "QtBackend.h"

int main()
{
    Widget* w = new Widget();
    w->doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've come that far. The problem is at the next stage:
Imagine you have container and element to add to this container. How would you design the method to add element to the container so that you don't have to cast internally?

Comment: This only allows compile-time selection of a backend.

Comment: @TomaszWiszkowski In this implementation, there's no `IButton` class. There are `IButton<GtkBitton>`, `IButton<QtButton>` etc. `IButton` is a typedef to one of them, selected at compile time.